# Can't deploy my current app to Heroku, Application error

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

This is my first time attempting to deploy a react App to Heroku so there's a good chance I missed something out.

However currently everytime I try to run 'heroku open' I get an application error. When I run 'heroku logs --tail' I get this error message.

```
2020-06-09T15:30:19.991895+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=floating-hamlet-41018.herokuapp.com request_id=541e3c31-5899-4d5e-a8e7-7a57770135f5 fwd="77.97.218.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-09T15:30:29.439518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=floating-hamlet-41018.herokuapp.com request_id=fd0aff85-5a4b-4d3c-9e62-f639ecfab98c fwd="77.97.218.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-09T15:30:32.592482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=floating-hamlet-41018.herokuapp.com request_id=1eb4f2ec-96eb-4baa-bf9f-ff3b54bb16e3 fwd="77.97.218.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-09T15:36:12.451266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=floating-hamlet-41018.herokuapp.com request_id=9899253b-8a31-4afa-8bcd-ec9632bc73dd fwd="77.97.218.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-09T15:42:40.322514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=floating-hamlet-41018.herokuapp.com request_id=13cd4bec-baab-4e9e-873f-8172d141826a fwd="77.97.218.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-09T15:42:44.196962+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=floating-hamlet-41018.herokuapp.com request_id=008e86ef-8738-499c-b873-a7e20c892a4b fwd="77.97.218.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "weather-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.12.0",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const api = {
  key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
}

function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

  const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          setWeather(result);
          setQuery(''); 
          console.log(result);
        });
      }
    } 

  const dateBuilder =(d) => {
    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec"];
     let days = ["Sunday", "Mondy", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

     let day = days[d.getDay()];
     let date = d.getDate();
     let month = months[d.getMonth()];
     let year = d.getFullYear();

     return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
    }
    return (
      // (Condition) ? 'return value' :
    <div className={(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ?
     ((weather.main.temp > 15 && weather.main.temp < 30 && weather.weather[0].main === "Clouds") ? 'app warmcloudy' : (weather.main.temp > 15 && weather.main.temp < 30 && weather.weather[0].main === "Clear") ? 'app warm' 
     : (weather.main.temp < 1 && weather.weather[0].main !== "Rain") ? 'app ice' : (weather.weather[0].main === "Thunderstorm") ? 'app lightning' : 
     (weather.weather[0].main === "Snow") ? 'app snow' : (weather.main.temp >= 30 && weather.weather[0].main !== "Rain") ? 'app hot' : 
     (weather.main.temp < 6 && weather.weather[0].main === "Clear") ? 'app coldclear' : 
     (weather.weather[0].main === "Rain") ? 'app raining' : 'app clear') : 'app'}>
      <main>
        <div className="search-box">
          <input 
          type="text"
          className="search-bar"
          placeholder="Search for a location..."
          onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          value={query}
          onKeyPress={search}
          />
        </div>
        {(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? (
       <div> 
        <div className="location-box">
          <div className="location">{weather.name}, {weather.sys.country}</div>
          <div className="date">{dateBuilder(new Date())}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="weather-box">
          <div className="temp">
            {Math.round(weather.main.temp)}°c
            {console.log(weather.weather[0].main)}
          </div>
          <div className="weather">{weather.weather[0].main}</div>
          <div className="feelslike">Feels like {Math.round(weather.main.feels_like)}°c</div>
          <div className="windspeed">Wind Speed: {Math.round(weather.wind.speed)}mph</div>
        </div>
       </div>
       ) : ('')}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

If I'm missing anything please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Is your app just React or does it have a server?  If it's just a React app(static page) you need to use another site to host it.  I generally use [netlify](https://www.netlify.com) for this.  Super easy to use and can connect directly to your github repo to monitor changes for rebuilding like you can do with heroku

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a React app! No server involved

Comment: That's the problem.  Try using netlify or another static site hosting service to host your app instead of netlify.  With heroku you need a server to host an app

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using heroku CLI, you can try again with these steps:

1. Go to terminal, navigate to your project directory.
2. Enter `heroku login` and then press any key, it will open up the login screen in browser.
3. After successful login, come back to terminal and enter `heroku create -b https://morning-atoll-33546.herokuapp.com/`
4. git push Heroku master

and it should be deployed and will give you the url where it is hosted.

and make sure all file names are capitalize except index.js for eg: app.js should be App.js